# Are GRE/GMAT or other certificates needed for academic career after PhD?

Tags: career-path, job-search, postdocs, certification

My interest is mainly in computer science. I am wondering if, for a post-doc or an assintant professor poistion, the certifications such as GRE or GMAT are reqired or if they don't have any relevance.

My interest is both for Europe and USA.

Also, what can be said about language certifications, such as TOEFL and IELTS? 
Are they required too?

Comment: I have not seen any case in which one of those tests was required for a postdoc or asst. prof. job (in engineering at least)!

Comment: GRE and GMAT are not certifications. They're assessments, and they only matter in the context of applying to graduate school.

Answer (score 6):

Good GRE and GMAT scores will make it easier to be accepted into the graduate program of your choice. They will have no bearing on post doc hiring decisions

Similarly language testing is used to ensure that English problems will not prevent you from being successful in graduate school. Once admitted your language skills will continue to improve during your studies and your TOEFL scores will no longer matter.

The only exception to this would be if you want to work for a test prep company that trains student for the GRE, GMAT or TOEFL. Ignoring this possibility, your testing results are not important after you are accepted by the University and begin your studies.